# Get order id (not increment id) on success page?

Tags: magento2, order-success-page

I am running **Magento 2.2** and I want to get the order id on the success page.

```
$block->getOrderId() // returns 000000008 for example
```

I do not want 000000008, but the real ID from the database, like 11616. How could I do that on the success page?

Thanks!

Comment: Please specify the file where you are using this code. You should try getting order object there and then you can use $order->getId() .

Comment: this code magento is using on order success.phtml file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to customize prepareBlockData in `vendor/magento/module-checkout/Block/Onepage/Success.php` .

Just need to change one line

```
'order_id'  => $order->getIncrementId()  to 'order_id'  => $order->getId()
```

Note: Recommended way to write files .
 Don't change core files, create block and override with `< preference >` in `di.xml` file.